Function checking blank position is not working
I need to create measure that compares Currency from different tables. Simple if one column is empty then take data from other.
Material



Material no
Name




1234
Mat 1


5678
Mat 2


1290
Mat 3



Budget



Material no
Currency




1234
USD


5678



1290
EUR



JIRA



Material no
Currency




1234



5678
EUR


1290
EUR



Expected result



Material no
Currency




1234
USD


5678
EUR


1290
EUR



I've created measure
Miara-test = 
VAR Purchase_filter = MAXX('Budget','Budget'[Currency]) 
RETURN IF( ISBLANK(Purchase_filter)) || Purchase_filter = "", MAXX(JIRA,JIRA[Currency]), MAXX('Budget','Budget'[Currency]))

Due to whatever reason, I've received table that returns only currency in case they're same in both source data



Material no
Currency




1234



5678



1290
EUR




This is not what you asked for but i would suggest you use the related table feature to create a new table with the all the data lined up and then create a measure of that.

What should it return if the Currencies are different from both tables? For example: Jira returns USD and Budget returns EUR?

Try this Measure:
Currency_Measure = 

VAR BudgetCurrency = MINX(Budget, [Currency]) //since there is a relationship from Material to Budget, this gets the related value.
VAR JiraCurrency = MINX(JIRA, [Currency]) //gets related value

RETURN SWITCH(TRUE()
        , BudgetCurrency = BLANK(), JiraCurrency
        , JiraCurrency = BLANK(), BudgetCurrency
        , JiraCurrency = BudgetCurrency, JiraCurrency //doesn't matter which one we output
        , "" //if they both have data but are different, output blank for now
)

Example Output:

Material 1111 is an example where both the Currencies are different nonblank values.
Data Model:

The Material table is related to both Budget and Jira but the Material no column.
